# H2O in docker-compose - which folders to mount to persist all data?

Tags: docker, h2o

Trying to use H20 with docker-compose. Their website has [instructions on running with Docker](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/1/docs-website/h2o-docs/docker.html) which I'm using as a basis.

**I can't work out how to persist the appropriate folders to keep the models accessible in H2O Flow. Which folders do I need to persist locally for this?**

I've used the [Dockerfile here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/Dockerfile) and the `docker-compose.yaml` below. I'm able to store models locally by mounting the `/tmp` folder, but which other folders do I need to mount?

```yaml
version: '3.1'
services :
  h2o-svc:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: h2o:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./app/h2o_models:/tmp
    ports:
      - 54321:54321
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2O-3 has an in-memory architecture.

It does not write anything to disk unless you ask it to, and the location it persists to (when saving a model, for example) is the location you manually give it.

I suggest you try this without docker first, to get the hang of what to expect when H2O-3 restarts.